# Why do I get a 'Hash Join' and FTS on this PostgreSQL query?

Tags: performance, postgresql, join, hash, indexing

I'm trying to optimize the following scenario:

In worded format: I have 2 tables, `alerts` and `user_devices`; in `user_devices` we track whether a device coupled to a `user_id` wants to get notifications or not and in `alerts` table we track user-to-notifier relation. Basically the task is to select every `user_id` that has any alerts and allows notifications to any of the devices registered to it.

Table 'alerts', around 900k records:

```
               Table "public.alerts"
   Column    |           Type           | Modifiers 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------
 id          | uuid                     | not null
 user_id     | uuid                     | 
 target_id   | uuid                     | 
 target_type | text                     | 
 added_on    | timestamp with time zone | 
 old_id      | text                     | 
Indexes:
    "alerts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "one_alert_per_business_per_user" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_id, target_id)
    "addedon" btree (added_on)
    "targetid" btree (target_id)
    "userid" btree (user_id)
    "userid_targetid" btree (user_id, target_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "alerts_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

Table 'user_devices', around 12k records:

```
                Table "public.user_devices"
       Column        |           Type           | Modifiers 
---------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 id                  | uuid                     | not null
 user_id             | uuid                     | 
 device_id           | text                     | 
 device_token        | text                     | 
 push_notify_enabled | boolean                  | 
 device_type         | integer                  | 
 device_name         | text                     | 
 badge_count         | integer                  | 
 added_on            | timestamp with time zone | 
Indexes:
    "user_devices_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "push_notification" btree (push_notify_enabled)
    "user_id" btree (user_id)
    "user_id_push_notification" btree (user_id, push_notify_enabled)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "user_devices_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

The following query:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) 
from alerts a 
  inner join user_devices ud on a.user_id = ud.user_id 
WHERE ud.push_notify_enabled = true;
```

Takes about 3 seconds and produces the following plan:

```
explain select COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) from alerts a inner join user_devices ud on a.user_id = ud.user_id WHERE ud.push_notify_enabled = true;
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=49777.32..49777.33 rows=1 width=16)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=34508.97..48239.63 rows=615074 width=16)
         Hash Cond: (ud.user_id = a.user_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on user_devices ud  (cost=0.00..480.75 rows=9202 width=16)
               Filter: push_notify_enabled
         ->  Hash  (cost=20572.32..20572.32 rows=801732 width=16)
               ->  Seq Scan on alerts a  (cost=0.00..20572.32 rows=801732 width=16)
```

What am I missing, is there a way to speed this up?

Thank you.

== edit ==

As per suggestion, tried to move condition inside the join, no difference:

```
=> explain select COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) from alerts a inner join user_devices ud on a.user_id = ud.user_id and ud.push_notify_enabled;
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=49777.32..49777.33 rows=1 width=16)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=34508.97..48239.63 rows=615074 width=16)
         Hash Cond: (ud.user_id = a.user_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on user_devices ud  (cost=0.00..480.75 rows=9202 width=16)
               Filter: push_notify_enabled
         ->  Hash  (cost=20572.32..20572.32 rows=801732 width=16)
               ->  Seq Scan on alerts a  (cost=0.00..20572.32 rows=801732 width=16)
```

So, no way to get away from 2 FTS? If I could at least get it to somehow use the index on 'alerts' table, would've been great..

== edit ==

Adding `EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

```
=> explain ANALYZE select COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) from alerts a inner join user_devices ud on a.user_id = ud.user_id and ud.push_notify_enabled;
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=49777.32..49777.33 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=5254.355..5254.356 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=34508.97..48239.63 rows=615074 width=16) (actual time=1824.607..2863.635 rows=614768 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (ud.user_id = a.user_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on user_devices ud  (cost=0.00..480.75 rows=9202 width=16) (actual time=0.048..16.784 rows=9186 loops=1)
               Filter: push_notify_enabled
         ->  Hash  (cost=20572.32..20572.32 rows=801732 width=16) (actual time=1824.229..1824.229 rows=801765 loops=1)
               Buckets: 4096  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 990kB
               ->  Seq Scan on alerts a  (cost=0.00..20572.32 rows=801732 width=16) (actual time=0.047..878.429 rows=801765 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 5255.427 ms
(9 rows)
```

=== Edit ===

Adding requested configuration. Most of it is Ubuntu PG9.1 defaults:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main# cat postgresql.conf | grep -e "work_mem" -e "effective_cache" -e "shared_buff" -e "random_page_c"
shared_buffers = 24MB           # min 128kB
#work_mem = 1MB             # min 64kB
#maintenance_work_mem = 16MB        # min 1MB
#wal_buffers = -1           # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
#random_page_cost = 4.0         # same scale as above
#effective_cache_size = 128MB
```

Comment: Well PostgreSQL needs to visit nearly every row in the alerts table. So the seq scan will be the fastest thing to do. If you are on 9.2 it might actually do a index only scan on the `userid` index.

Comment: Is there any difference if you move the `where` condition to the `join` condition like `inner join user_devices ud on a.user_id = ud.user_id and ud.push_notify_enabled`? There is no need for the `= true` part BTW.

Comment: Will try moving and see if it helps. Afk now, will check in a couple of hours. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: tried, didn't help, see edit :(

Comment: please add the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` that will show you **both** the expected and observed number of rows. (maybe your statistics are off, or absent)

Comment: Thanks. Please also add the settings for {work_mem effective_cache_size, shared_buffers and random_page_cost} from your postgres. conf. I get the feeling that your work_mem is high, the buffers low and the page_cost still set to its default 4.0 .

Comment: I would start by setting random_page_cost to a lower version ( ~1.5) and *maybe* lower work_mem (temporarily, 1M looks good). This can be done just for the session, by a `SET parameter_name parameter_value;` statement. BRB

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23020/discussion-between-favoretti-and-wildplasser)

Comment: @wildplasser: care to join the chat for a bit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the index by a partial index:

```
DROP INDEX    user_id_push_notification ;
CREATE INDEX    user_id_push_notification ON user_devices (user_id)
 WHERE push_notify_enabled =True
 ;
```

, and set random_page_cost to lower value:

SET random_page_cost = 1.1;

Caused an `Index Scan using push_notification on user_devices ud` for me (< 300ms). YMMV.

The seqscan on alerts seems more or less unavoidable, since you expect 800K/900K := 88%) rows. An index scan would only be effective if the rowsize were very large, IMHO.

UPDATE: adding the users table to the query seems to force a triple index scan. (but approx the same time )

```
explain  ANALYZE
select COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id)
from alerts a
join user_devices ud on a.user_id = ud.user_id
join users us on a.user_id = us.id
WHERE ud.push_notify_enabled = true;
```

Comment: 9.1 or 9.2? Causes no difference for me, but I'm upgrading to 9.2.2 as we speak.

Comment: 9.1.2. I need to upgrade, too ;-)

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? Your proposed query forces a triple Seq scan for me :)

Comment: Strange. I did change  the uuid's to integer and serial, though. (for easyer insert by generate_series(), which doesnt seem to support uuids )

Comment: I'd gladly shoot the guy who used uuids for this database in the head, but he's about 6000 miles further away. :(

Comment: Aha, interesting fact. settings `random_page_cost` to 1.1 triggered index scan, but doubled the query time :)

Comment: The obvious change would be to change the PK+FK keys to surrogate serial/int (or bigserial/bigint), and use the existing uuids as alternate ("satelite") keys. (just add a "unique" constraint for them will do)

Comment: Well, as concluded, there's not much I can do in this situation, so upvoting both and accepting @wildplasser since he spent some time testing stuff as well :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23025/discussion-between-wildplasser-and-favoretti)

Comment: Hmm, I managed to rewrite the query in such a way that time spent reduced to 2.5 sec. `SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT distinct a.user_id FROM alerts a JOIN  user_devices ud on a.user_id=ud.user_id WHERE ud.push_notify_enabled ORDER by a.user_id) as count;`. Apparently distinct works faster if you enforce `order by` on an indexed field. This way I get 2-index merge on the subquery join.

Comment: Mooi man! Here it goes from 360ms to 260 ms. (synthetic data with all integer keys. we dont want no stinking uuids here ...)

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, the real hog is the full scan of `alerts` table. Logically, for given user ID, *any and all* records in `alerts` may match that user ID.

You have one condition that might limit the scan: `push_notify_enabled`; you don't need rows where it's `false`. But you lack an index on this column, so full scan on `alerts` is still the fastest way to join the two tables.

<s>Try using a bitmap index on `push_notify_enabled`, if your version of Postgres supports it. (Obviously, btree index on a 2-value column is no good.)</s>

To speed up the query you have to limit the number of rows to be scanned in `alerts`, that is, to add a condition on some indexed column of `alerts`. Then an index scan instead of a full scan might be possible, if the index is selective enough.

For instance, you could filter by target ID, or by some date-related column, if this makes sense.

If you have 900k alerts which are all active, and can be arbitrarily shared betwen users, you have little choice; probably adding RAM to keep the `alerts` table always cached might help. (Adding hardware is often the easiest and most cost-effective solution.)

AFAICT you are only interested in alerts that are associated with push notifications. If users with push notifications never share an alert with users without push notifications, you may effectively split `alerts` by this condition.

If you had bitmap indexes, you might move `push_notify_enabled` column to `alerts`.  Else, you might try to physically split it on that column, using [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html). If the number of alerts with push notifications is significantly lower than total alerts, a far smaller portion of `alerts` will be scanned to make the join.

Comment: Unfortunately no bitmap index available here it seems. Another question (might be total bs, but just thinking aloud) - what if I transfer the `push_notify_enabled` to alerts table?

Comment: My bad — I for some reason mistook `push_notify_enabled` for a column from `alerts`. I will edit my response.

Comment: Trying to upgrade the thing to 9.2 for a chance. Gah, I need to learn more about postgres, this is so frustrating :)

Comment: @favoretti: "Experience is what you get when you don't get what you wanted" :)

Comment: Also: good judgement stems from experience; experience stems from bad judgement.